# how to assign merged type value to a sub type in javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I title is a littble bit wired I know that :(

I got 2 components, `studentBasicComponent` and `studentContactorComponent`. so for each component, I create models for data binding (the code I pasted is simplified, in face there are quite a few properties)

```
export default interface StudentBasic {
  id: Number,
  name: String,
  birth: Date,
  gender: String
}

export default interface StudentContactor {
  name: String,
  phone: String
}

export type Student = StudentBasic & StudentContactor;
```

Short question is:

If I have `const student: Student = { ... }`, how can I assign it to `const basic:StudentBasic`  and `const contractor:StudentContactor` as simple as I can?

For detail, we retrieve data from the server with a single request, so what I get from the api is something like.

```
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    "student-basic": studentBasicComponent,
    "student-contactor": studentContactorComponent,
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  }
  setup(props) {
    const studentBasicData: StudentBasic = reactive( {
        id: 0,
        name: "",
        birth: moment(),
        gender: "",
    });
    const contactor: StudentContactor = reactive({
      name: "",
      phone: "",
    });

    onMounted(async() => {
      const data: Student = await getStudent(props.id);

      // Here, how to assign value to studentBasicData and studentContactor
    });

    return {
      studentBasicData,
      studentContactor,
    }
  },
})
```

So after I get the whole data `const data: Student = await getStudent(props.id);` , how can I assign to `studentBasicData` and `studentContactor`?

I don't want to manually set value for each property by `studentBasicData.name = data.name`

(using Vue 3 + Typescript)

Comment: Well these are just interfaces & its JavaScript. For me either I will create two modal classes ( for each `studentBasicComponent` & `studentContactorComponent` ) which has a method, `parseJson(data:Student)` then returns the `studentBasicComponent` or `studentContactorComponent`. Or else I'll just create two copies of `data` object. then delete unwanted properties. `let basic = deleteUnwanted(dataCpy, "BASIC") as studentBasicComponent`

Comment: TypeScript it just to specify type, it does not mean if you created one type by doing & operation then you can pick values for any of option, you have to do it manually at most you can do it by different way thats set, meaning instead of using `.` operation you can use like const { id, name } = someObject; // having { id:1, name: 'John' } and then create new object like const obj  = { id, name }